# PHP Template Engine built by url

Tags: php, template-engine, explode, geturl

I am searching for a kind of dynamic template engine which I want to built by the url. So if my url is like localhost/root/this/is/the/path/to/signup.php the php code should watch for the file signup.php in the directory this/is/the/path/to/

For this time I am using arrays of the url like the following code shows:

```
$url = isset($_GET['url']) ? $_GET['url'] : null;
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);

if (empty($url[0])) {
    $url[0] = "path/startpage.php";
}

if (isset($url[2])) {
    require "path/error.php";
} else if (isset($url[1])) {

    $file1 = 'path/' .$url[0].'/'.$url[1].'/'.$url[1].'.php';

    if (file_exists($file1)) {
        require $file1;
    } else {
        require "error.php";
    }

} else if (isset($url[0])) {

    $file0 = 'path/'.$url[0].'/'.$url[0].'.php';

    if (file_exists($file0)) {
        require $file0;
    } else {
    require "path/error.php";
    }
}
```

But with this script I have to do this for every case and this is not so nice. I want to have a solution where the code is looking for the whole url, goes to the directory and require an error or the file, if it exists.

Could you help me please?

Comment: Of course you have to check everytime if the file exists. I Don't really get what you want to change.

Comment: I want something like that ` $file = path/url` and the url should insert automatically. Is this possible?

Comment: I see what is the value in `$_GET['url']`?

Answer (score 0):

The Titon\View library handles this quite easily: https://github.com/titon/View

If an array of paths is passed in for the template, it will generate dynamic lookup paths. https://github.com/titon/View/blob/master/src/Titon/View/View.php#L127

Example:

```
$view = new Titon\View\View();
$view->addPath('/path/to/views/');
$parsed = $view->run(['path', 'to', 'lookup/folder', 'templateName]);
```

Can also take a look at the tests to see it in action: https://github.com/titon/View/blob/master/tests/Titon/View/ViewTest.php